# How to get requested url from ajax response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my project I have several ajax global events.

In

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqxhr, settings) {
   // 
});
```

I can get requested url from `settings.url`

But how can I get url from response from this request in

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, jqxhr) {
    //
});
```

The only object that contains requested url here is `arguments[2].url`

Is there other way to obtain requested url from response, because I'm not sure in such object as `arguments[2].url`?

Comment: *because I'm not sure in such object as `arguments[2].url`* ...why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arguments[2]` is exactly the same as `settings`

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, jqxhr, settings) {
    // arguments[2] === settings
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in your complete of ajax try using like this:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  alert(settings.url);
});
```

see documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)